# Unmapped column in a dependence restriction in SSIS

Tags: ssis, ssis-2012

I have an issue in SSIS in the dependence restriction. I am trying to import data from an excel file. I have used the EXCEL FILE, that it is connected to a derived column. After we have the UNION ALL component. Everytime I try to assign one column to the Account column it throws an error telling the metadata...
[image]

if I click in the restriction dependence between the UNION ALL component and the DERIVED COLUMN component IT shows that account is not mapped... but in the source (excel source component) it is mapped!!! it is driving me mad.

[image]

why i cannot add the account in this table?! to the source column? i HAVE TRIED to remove and recreating everything again... same problem again. I even opened a new package to test.. driving me mad.

Comment: If you reset metadata it will show up the  output column. try building same package with mappings and test it

Comment: how to reset metadata? is there an option to do it?

Comment: Change connection name and reconnect, it should prompt you to reset metadata

Comment: this is a very odd way to reset metadata... it should exist an option in the menu if this is so common to happen. I will do it. Thanks. :)

Comment: it did not work to rename the connection manager.  maybe i need to close the program and try again. this metadata is hell.

Comment: Or right click on flat file ,go to advance editor go onto output properties and rest column value

Comment: WELL, I do not know what are you referring... (i am using an excel file with 24 sheets). I went to the excel source, output COLUMNS, I have erased the ACCOUNT column. OK. Anfd then I have added it again to the excel source.... and the problem remains..

Answer (score 0):

does it make sense that the solution was to COPY one good excel source and then just change the new sheet?  If I created from root with a new excel source it would throw always the previous errors. So it was just to copy the excel source that was working and then just changing to the desired (new) sheet. and it worked this way. Reset the metadata seems to be flick in SSIS. I would like if someone could share a secure way to do it!